# How to set logout redirect in felogin plugin in TYPO3 6.2?

Tags: typo3, logout, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using felogin - to get it to work I set it up in TypoScript in my root template:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
  storagePid = 40,38,36,35,51
  showForgotPasswordLink = 1
  redirectMode = groupLogin,userLogin,login,loginError
  redirectPageLogout = 6
...
```

It works fine, except when I try to logout while being on a page with restricted access because then it tries to find that restricted-page and for those cases I set up the install tool to redirect it to a "Page not found" template.

I noticed the logout-form action always points to the page ID I'm currently on:

```
<form action="index.php?id=49" target="_top" method="post">
```

so that's not what I want...I would like it to always be `action="index.php?id=6"` but my `redirectPageLogout = 6` line didn't manage to change it.

Anyone an idea how can I change this?
In the felogin html template there's just `###ACTION_URI###` and idk where it gets that from in the logout-form but I wanna play by the rules and not change it in the template directly...unless there's no other way.

Comment: Its fine, when your login-form action points to the page ID, where the felogin plugin is in, cause only the felogin plugin can handle, what you want to do with felogin (validate, login, logout, redirect,...)

Comment: Ok, I understand from your comment that it's fine, so I shouldn't mess wih it...? But how do I get it to redirect to a non-restricted page after I logout in a restricted one? Right now I just changed the template to `index.php?id=6` instead of `###ACTION_URI###`and it works fine, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have access to a login-/logout-plugin after your logout is processed to get the forwarding working.
So if your logout plugin is on a page which is only invisible for logged in user. the logout is processed, but your redirect can't be processed (the default-handling of TYPO3 takes over and throws you to a page which is accessable). The same occurs if only the plugin itself is only visible for logged in users.

if you target the logout form directly to a page with a plugin visible for all, first the logout and secondly the redirect can be processed always.

Comment: What should I do now then? Was replacing `###ACTION_URI###`with `index.php?id=6` fine then? My plugin "felogin" is always visible on every page.

Comment: Try to change only a minimum of your configuration, to se, when your error appears. Start with not seeting any 'Page not found', to ensure, your felogin redirect works as expected.

Comment: replacing the ###ACTION_URI### with a fixed url for the plugins on every page might be invalid if that url also is used on login (from every page). But primarily it depends on your expected behaviour. if that page 6 is the page where a visitor should land after any logout (without redirect), or everyone is redirected to another page anyway it is ok. If your login also is targetting page 6 and a redirect moves your visitors to the correct page, still ok.

Comment: Try to seperate login & logout. If you use content elements: One login plugin will handle the login mechanism and redirect to a secured page (“After Successful Login Redirect to Page“/redirectPageLogin) and should be hidden at any login. Another login plugin will handle logut actions only (“After Logout Redirect to Page”/ redirectPageLogout) and is shown at any login. This way the ACTION_URI is build using the »redirectPageLogout« pid.